# ValueError: Substring not found when using str.index

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am a beginner in python and the following code I am trying

```
input_number = raw_input("Please input the number:")
print type(input_number)
if(input_number.index('0')):
    print "Not Accepted"
else:
    print "Accepted"
```

When I am giving the input for example '1234506' its showing "Not accepted" which is valid but when I am giving '123456' its throwing error "Substring not found".
So how can I print the else part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you enter 123456 or 1234506, python considers it as a string.

Now, when you use string_object.index(substring), it looks for the occurrence of substring (in your case, the substring is '0') in the string_object. If '0' is present, the method returns the index at which the substring is present, otherwise, it throws an error.

you can use the following instead :

```
if '0' in input_number :
    print 'not accepted'
else :
    print 'accepted'
```

Answer (score 5):

`str.index` errors out when there is no match. In this situation, you can either choose to handle the error, or use `str.find` instead which returns an integer value between -1 and `len(input_number)`, or do a set membership test on the original string.

**Option 1**

Conversion to `set` lookup:

```
if '0' not in set(input_number):
    print "Accepted"
else:
    print "Not accepted"
```

---

**Option 2**

Using `try...except` to handle the `ValueError`.

```
try:
    input_number.index('0')
    print "Not accepted"

except ValueError:
    print "Accepted"
```

---

**Option 3**

Using `str.find`:

```
if input_number.find('0') < 0:
    print "Accepted"
else:
    print "Not accepted"
```